# Pass data from NodeJs to HTML

Tags: html, node.js

I am dealing with is an issue for a long time, I am using Node js to execute power-shell code.

I am getting the correct "data" but how I can pass it to the 
   client(html)?

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn,child;
const app = express();

app.use('/static', express.static('public'))
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

//PORT
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port);

child = spawn("powershell.exe", ["C:\\Users\\mohammed.alneama\\Desktop\\CCT\\getWinInfo.ps1"]);

child.stdout.on("data",function(data){
    console.log( "User: " + data)
});

child.stderr.on("data",function(data){
    console.log("Powershell Errors: " + data);
});

child.on("exit",function(){
    console.log("Powershell Script finished");
});

child.stdin.end(); //end input (edited)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the shell execution output to a `promise`, hope it helps

```
const express = require('express');
let shellData;let shellErr;
let shellPromise = new Promise(function(res,rej){
    shellData=res;shellErr=rej;
});
const path = require('path');
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn,child;
const app = express();

app.use('/static', express.static('public'))
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var data = await shellPromise;
    //use the express template engine to pass this data to html
    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

//PORT
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port);

child = spawn("powershell.exe", ["C:\\Users\\mohammed.alneama\\Desktop\\CCT\\getWinInfo.ps1"]);

child.stdout.on("data",function(data){
    console.log( "User: " + data);
    shellData(data)
});

child.stderr.on("data",function(data){
    console.log("Powershell Errors: " + data);
    shellErr(data);
});

child.on("exit",function(){
    console.log("Powershell Script finished");
});

child.stdin.end(); //end input
```

Answer (score 0):

First define a route (this will execute the powershell script when the route is accessed):

```
app.get("/executePowerShellScript", function(req, res) {
    res.send("Output of script")
})
```

Then move your logic into that route:

```
app.get("/executePowerShellScript", function(req, res) {
    child = spawn("powershell.exe", ["C:\\Users\\mohammed.alneama\\Desktop\\CCT\\getWinInfo.ps1"])

    child.stdout.on("data",function(data){
        console.log( "User: " + data)
    });

    child.stderr.on("data",function(data){
        console.log("Powershell Errors: " + data);
    });

    child.on("exit",function(){
        console.log("Powershell Script finished");
    });

    child.stdin.end(); //end input (edited)
})
```

Now we need to make a few adjustments to make it work:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()

app.use('/static', express.static('public'))
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
})

app.get("/executePowerShellScript", function(req, res) {
    const spawn = require("child_process").spawn

    var powerShellOutput = {stdout: "", stderr: ""}

    var child = spawn("powershell.exe", ["C:\\Users\\mohammed.alneama\\Desktop\\CCT\\getWinInfo.ps1"])

    child.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
        // capture STDOUT data
        powerShellOutput.stdout += data.toString()
    })

    child.stderr.on("data", function(data) {
        // capture STDERR data
        powerShellOutput.stderr += data.toString()
    })

    // send response when script is done
    child.on("exit", function() {
        var response = "<h1>STDOUT</h1>"
        response += "<pre>" + powerShellOutput.stdout + "</pre>"
        response += "<h2>STDERR</h2>"
        response += "<pre>" + powerShellOutput.stderr + "</pre>"

        // here we send the response.
        res.send(response)
    })

    child.stdin.end() // end input (edited)
})

//PORT
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port)
```

Answer (score 0):

You only missing  `res.send` and then you can send data to html . you can read more about that in [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).
Example:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
    res.send("this will send to hmtl");
});
```